# When is public humiliation and slander illegal?

Tags: canada, slander

There is a activist/vigilantly group called [Creep Catchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creep_Catcher) who pretend to be underage children selling sex. Then when a pedophile agrees to meet in person, they show up with video cameras, broadcast it live, and basically get the person to admit he's a pedophile.

Recently there was a case where they did this to a disabled man and had initially pretended the girl was of age, but I don't want to discuss morality.

It's my understanding that it's illegal to slander a person on a very public scale and that public humiliation isn't allowed. By the Creep Catchers own description, their job is to publicly humiliate pedophiles using the internet (but I would suspect a lot of the tactics would count as entrapment). When is this sort of activity illegal?

There was another case where they knocked on a door and when the person answered they started aggressively accusing her of being a pedophile and broadcasted it. Whether or not it was true, she denied that she was and said someone else was pretending to be her online. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Canada as in the US, [truth is a defence](http://www.canlaw.com/caveat/copy%20of%20defamation.htm#.WDYftVyW73g) against defamation. Additionally, if the plaintiff makes the statement, then the defendant didn't, and the plaintiff would have no basis for pursuing a person who managed to get him to defame himself. If the people were to accuse the person of committing a crime (sex with a minor), then the potential for defamation exists, if that accusation was communicated to a third person (excluding police -- you can accuse a person to the police). In that case, the defendants might attempt to prove that the accusation was true, but I don't know how they would show that. If all they could do is prove that the guy acted kind of pervey but that actually accused him of having sex with a minor, then they would probably be in legal hot water. If they accuse him of doing what he actually did, that is not defamation. There is no law against getting a person to publicly admit to wrong-doing. "Entrapment" is something that only law enforcement can do (and it's illegal).

Since it is not illegal in Canada for a person to offer sex for money (it is illegal to be a customer, though), the youths are not doing anything illegal. In the US, though, that would be illegal, so they too might get in trouble.

Comment: I don't think "entrapment" is actually illegal, just that evidence gained by it is inadmissible

Comment: Generally speaking, attempting to have sex with a minor or a person believed to be a minor (even if they are not) for money is a crime. So, it would probably be illegal in Canada too. I'm not clear why the question asker thinks that this would be slander. And humiliation is usually prohibited only when unjustified and extreme.

Comment: Well, in some jurisdictions (Indonesia I think) truth is not a defense, so saying that X committed a crime when they did is indeed defamation. Sometimes this is subsumed more general laws against insulting.